# a simple C code but compile generate many errors in Suse

Tags: c, suse

I write a simple .c file and compile it in my Sesu11.But it has many errors even though it just include a simple printf sentence.I wonder that is it caused by my compile environment is not correct and how to check my environment.Thanks.
Here is my C code and the compile result.

```
    [Linux:/si/usr/hrl]vi hello.c

    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
            printf("hello world!");
            return 0;
    }
 [Linux:/si/usr/hrl]gcc -O hello.c -o hello
        In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:37,
                         from hello.c:1:
        /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/include/stddef.h:214: error：expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘typedef’
        In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:78,
                         from hello.c:1:
        /usr/include/libio.h:332: error：expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/libio.h:364: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/libio.h:373: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/libio.h:495: error：expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_IO_sgetn’
        In file included from hello.c:1:
        /usr/include/stdio.h:301: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:307: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:319: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:326: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:368: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:370: error：格式字符串实参不是字符串型
        /usr/include/stdio.h:372: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:374: error：格式字符串实参不是字符串型
        /usr/include/stdio.h:644: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:647: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:657: error：expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:687: error：expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fread’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:693: error：expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fwrite’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:715: error：expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fread_unlocked’
        /usr/include/stdio.h:717: error：expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fwrite_unlocked’
```

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with your gcc installation.  The header files and the compiler seem to be incompatible on your platform.

Comment: Are your /usr/include/libio.h or /usr/include/stdio.h somehow corrupted?

Comment: Also you should use int main (void)

Comment: I also guess it was some wrong with my gcc installation and try to reinstall it. But now I get a trouble that how I uninstall it because the installation is completed by myself.

Comment: Your install is broken somewhere. Re-install either devel suite or maybe your Suse.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I have let someone help me uninstall the whole gcc installation in the graphic user interface and try to reinstall of it by myself.But it seemed be difficult of me to install in the character interface without a guidance because I'm new for Sesu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header files appear to be corrupted.  Since you are on Suse, I'd recommend that you remove and then reinstall `devel_basis`:

```
 zypper remove devel_basis
 zypper install devel_basis
```

You should be fine after that!

Comment: linux-hjp:~ # zypper remove devel_basis
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'devel_basis' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'devel_basis' found.
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.
linux-hjp:~ # zypper install devel_basis
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'devel_basis' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'devel_basis' found.
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have done following your suggestion.But it seems to have some trouble to complete it.What should I do for next?

Comment: Which version of Suse are you running?

Comment: cat /proc/version

Linux version 3.0.76-0.11-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 08:21:43 UTC 2013 (ccab990)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty old.  Which package manager is on that, rpm?

Comment: I am
 afraid of not.

Comment: I have let someone help me uninstall the whole gcc installation in the graphic user interface and try to reinstall of it by myself.But it seemed be difficult of me to install in the character interface without a guidance because I'm new for Sesu

Comment: Well, installing GCC isn't exactly the right approach.  What you really want to install is `devel_basis` or whatever the equivalent is for 4.3.1.  This will *include* GCC in addition to all of the headers and such that you seem to be missing.

Comment: I run this command 'cat /proc/version' and showed that "Linux version 3.0.76-0.11-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 08:21:43 UTC 2013 (ccab990)".Could you suggest me one approval way to install it? Thanks.

Comment: I used the command of "zypper in gcc gcc-c++" to reinstall gcc and try the compile again.Unfortunately,I got the same result.

Comment: I think you may be right. There maybe something wrong with my `devel_basis` .But I can't use the `zypper` command instead  that find another devel packbage and then use  the `rpm` command to install it by force.After that ,the hello.c can be compiled without any errors.But I still double that how to use the 'zypper' command to reinstall it. Anyways,thank you for your help.